# Nagios plugin output character escaping

Tags: linux, nagios

Which characters in a Nagios plugin output need escaping other than pipe (|)?

How do I escape the pipe character and others?

Answer (score 1):

The [development guidelines](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html) do not specify a way to escape the `|`

The syntax of the first line is fix and not very flexible

```
SERVICE STATUS: First line of output | First part of performance data
```

and then in section 2.6 (Performance Data)

> Nagios 3 and newer will concatenate the parts following a "|" in a) the first line output by the plugin, and b) in the second to last line, into a string it passes to whatever performance data processing it has configured.

I would then assume that if you have a `|` in the `First line of output` part it will just interpreted as the beginning of the performance data.

Since the first line of output is not interpreted (up to the `|`) I would also assume that no characters have to be specially handled.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the `|` character is a reserved one to seperate plugin output from performance datas.

There is actually no way to escape it.

Regarding escaping other characters : Nagios uses STDOUT to display the plugin output. This means that it will display it as is.

However there is an exception for the `\` character. You will have to escape it with an extra `\`.

For example, to display `c:\Windows\system32` your plugin output should be `c:\\Windows\\system32`.